# EA Addin - API EA_OnNotifyContextItemModified

Tags: c#, .net, contextmenu, add-in, enterprise-architect

I created an addin in C#.
API `EA_OnNotifyContextItemModified` is triggered when in EA Application, the user selects an element, opens the Context Element window (by double click on element) and only press button OK without changing any content inside the Element. No content is modified, why this API is triggered?

Is there a way or an API to distinguish between:

1. select an element, open the Context Element Window (double click on element), press OK
2. select an element, open the Context Element Window (double click on element), modify something (for example the name of the element) and press OK

Comment: In C# code is there a way to get ModifiedDate database column info from the selected element? without using a query. I'm thinking that is a field on that object.

Comment: because the API is triggered even if the user only press OK button in "Content Element window"  without changing anything,  I figured out that I can check the time between API trigger and the date when the element was modified last time and it works : if ((DateTime.Now - element.Modified).Seconds > 1) return;

Comment: Geert, the code provided by you is not working because I need to check all the properties for that element between these two APIs to determine if the element changed or nod. Also to check all information from other tables related to that element.

Comment: Then you'll have to remember all the properties, and all information from other tables. I don't think there's any other option.

Comment: only to check condition if the element was modified in the last second:    if ((DateTime.Now - element.Modified).Seconds > 1) return;  if the time is bigger than 1 second then was only a PropertyChanged event on the element and probably the API was triggered but without modification on the element.  If is less than 1 second then it was a modification on the element

Comment: I guess that's a way to do it as well, if you are not interested in what has changed.